# Is it possible to freeze System.currentTimeMillis() for testing

Tags: java, testing

For some testing purposes I would like to predict exactly what `System.currentTimeMillis()` will return. Is there any way in which I can freeze or manually set what will return when `System.currentTimeMillis()` is called?

Comment: Can't you just store the result inside a variable instead and reuse it when needed ?

Comment: You'll have to replace all calls to System.currentTimeMillis() to a method that either calls it or returns a stored value if you want to override the behaviour.

Comment: Not if you hacked the JVM.

Comment: Not unless you are Charles Xavier

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001671/override-java-system-currenttimemillis-for-testing-time-sensitive-code

Answer (score 28):

I would strongly suggest that you avoid using `System.currentTimeMillis` (and `new Date()` etc) in your general code.

Instead, create a `Clock` interface representing "a service to give you the current time" and then create one implementation which *does* use `System.currentTimeMillis` or whatever, and a fake implementation that you can control explicitly.

Use dependency injection to make an instance of this service available to code which needs it. In production, use the `System.currentTimeMillis` version, and in testing use your fake.

This gives you the ability not just to stop time, but to set it to whatever you want - so you can have static test data which you know will never expire, and you can easily test tricky things around boundaries etc. I've used this approach very successfully in many projects, to the extent that in my Noda Time project it's *the* way of getting at "the current time".

Note that if you're doing any serious amount of time work in Java, I'd recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), and making your `Clock` interface return an `Instant`:

```
public interface Clock {
    Instant now();
}
```

Comment: On a related note: I'm really looking forward to [`java.time`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (a.k.a [JSR-310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)) to finally arrive in Java 8.

Answer (score 19):

**Yes, it is possible, but it is a test code smell.**

You can use a mocking library which enables you to mock static methods (as in this [PowerMock example](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#Mocking_Static_Method)), but you should avoid doing this, and encapsulate the time data as the other answers suggest.

This is how the test would look like, using *PowerMock* and *Mockito*:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class TestTime {

    @Test
    public void testTime() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        PowerMockito.when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(42l);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()); //prints 42

        //your test code here
    }

}
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey: No, that's a lower-case `L`, not a `1`.

Comment: :D. I *really* should finally retrain myself to use `L` instead. Oh well, let's call it a code-read-skill training bonus.

Comment: You can actually mock *that* method?  I'm amazed!

Comment: You can mock most methods with *PowerMock* (not sure about `native`). Of course, doesn't mean that you **should**, unless you're dealing with a legacy code monstrosity or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to freeze System.currentTimeMillis()? **NO**

You need to use a sort of wrapper around that time value if you want your code to be able to be tested

Answer (score 1):

No, You cann't set or freeze [System.currentTimeMills()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).
But if your requirement is something like that so in that case you can set time in variable and used when ever you want.but System.currentTimeMills() will always returns you the current time value in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

The new java.time package built into Java 8 includes a java.time.Clock interface "to allow alternate clocks to be plugged in as and when required. Use this instead.

Answer (score -5):

**Yes, solution exists:**

For testing purposes you may create your own wrapper System, for example

```
package my.pack;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class System
{
    // reuse standard System.out:
    public static PrintStream out = java.lang.System.out;

    // do anything with chosen method
    public static long currentTimeMillis()
    {
        return 1234567;
    }

}
```

and import it into your class which you want to test

```
import my.pack.System;
```

In that case all calls to System will be passed through your own System class.

**NOTE:**

- This is a solution for "how to intercept System.currentTimeMillis()"
- This is **NOT** suitable for automatic testing
- This is **NOT** an example of "how-to-design-a-good-program". If you ask for a good design, then you need to refactor your code, replace System.currentTimeMillis() - see other answers.

Comment: Are you suggesting to modify the source of the class under test *just during testing*? That would mean that the effective class you test is *not* the class you actually run in production!

Comment: Yes, you need to modify your class for testing purposes (append one line), and yes, for production you need to remove that import. But yes, you CAN change behaviour, and this is an easy way

Comment: Apart from the problem of testing a different class than what you're deploying, I also argue the "easy" way: automating this in a sane way would be a pain in the but.

Comment: Sure, this solution is not for automatic testing. By "easy" I mean less refactor: you don't need to change all the lines with currentTimeMillis() wherever they are