# How to Mock System.getenv() with JUnit5

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, junit-jupiter

I want to mock the System.getenv() method. I found only solutions for JUnit4 and PowerMockito.
I use the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my example of the test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) 
public class TestEnvVariable {

  @Mock
  System system;

  @Test
  public void shouldExpandPropertyContentToMatchingSysEnv() throws Exception {
      when(system.getenv("KEY")).thenReturn("VALUE");
      assertEquals("VALUE", "KEY");
  }
}
```

How to Mock System.getenv() with JUnit5?

Comment: So what’s the question?

Comment: @nkrivenko The question is in the header. :)

Comment: Has no one a idea?

Comment: This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404276/mock-system-class-to-get-system-properties) might help.

Comment: Sorry no this is for JUnit4

Answer (score 2):

You can create the object in the production code and mock that object in test.

In production code

```
Object Env{
       fun getVar() = System.getEnv("key")
}
```

then call with Env in production code

```
val callObject = Env.getVar()
```

In test file

```
@BeforeEach
fun setup() {
mockkObject(Env)
}
```

In test you can enter this -

```
every { Env.getVar() } returns "value"
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to be possible to mock `System`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182348/mockitoexception-when-trying-to-mock-java-lang-system)

System Stubs might also be a good alternative for [JUnit5](https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs#junit-5-extension)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `EnviromentVariableRule` at junit4.

Look at this link: https://www.baeldung.com/java-system-stubs#2-junit-4-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

Add the below configuration in maven-surefire-plugin dependency of your pom.xml, and run your junit test case as it is without making explicit changes related to System.getEnv() like Mocking System.class. This is not allowed/required.

If for example below is how your environment variable looks like :-

- Env Variable name := PROPERTY_NAME
- Env Variable Value := PROPERTY_VALUE

And if you access that environment variable using the below line
Java :- System.getEnv("PROPERTY_NAME");

Make the below changes to your pom.xml :-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
  <configuration>
   <environmentVariables>
      <PROPERTY_NAME>PROPERTY_VALUE</PROPERTY_NAME>
   </environmentVariables>
  </configuration>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using System Stubs.
Add this in POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>uk.org.webcompere</groupId>
  <artifactId>system-stubs-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then use stubs in tests:

```
@ExtendWith(SystemStubsExtension.class)
class WithEnvironmentVariables {

    @SystemStub
    private EnvironmentVariables variables =
        new EnvironmentVariables("KEY", "VALUE");

    @Test
    void hasAccessToEnvironmentVariables() {
        assertThat(System.getenv("KEY"))
            .isEqualTo("VALUE");
    }

    @Test
    void changeEnvironmentVariablesDuringTest() {
        variables.set("KEY", "bar");

        assertThat(System.getenv("KEY"))
            .isEqualTo("bar");
    }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs?tab=readme-ov-file#quickstart-junit-5