# How can i create good repeatable date tests in BDD?

Tags: java, spring, bdd, concordion

When i insert my business object in the database (with spring/hibernate), there are some date fields that are updated with the current date.

This is an important feature so i want to validate it in my testable specification.

The problem is that i want to see the field with the correct date, but as it's the current date, it changes every time.

I have a solution that could work but it's so hacky that i can't do it in good conscience.

It would be like this :

```
@Service
public class DateService {
  private Date fixedDate;

  public Date getCurrentDate() {
    if (fixedDate != null)
      return fixedDate;
    return new Date();
  }

  // setter / reset
}
```

And I @autowired it every time i need a new Date(). Then, when it's testing time, i fix the date so i know every "new" date would be this date.

How do you create good repeatable date based tests in your projects ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases when you can alter the underlying system, injecting an alternate clock  implementation works well. For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001671/override-java-system-currenttimemillis-for-testing-time-sensitive-code) shows various solutions, including Java 8's java.time.Clock interface.

For system tests, where you want to test the real implementation, instrument a Concordion spec such as:

`<p>The invoice date is set to <span c:assertEquals=getInvoiceDate()>today</span></p>`

Return a String value from the fixture method, containing either:

- "today" if the date is today, or
- a formatted date if the date is not today. This will then be shown as <del>today</del>20/12/2014 in the Concordion output.

Note: with this approach, be cautious of running your tests across midnight, since you run the risk of the date changing between retrieving the date and testing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it in the following manner:

1. In the test client, I would capture the current date and save it in a variable
2. I would then invoke the service to be tested (the service should get the current date and use it to update the model)
3. I would then invoke the service to obtain the relevant part of the model (R in CRUD); I would assume that the model representation contains the field with the date
4. I would then write an assertion to compare 2 dates: the one I got in the test client and the one that was set by the service

Answer (score 0):

To prevent having test code in your production environment, I would suggest to use a mock/stub framework to replace your DateService in your tests.
For example, you could use Mockito (https://github.com/mockito/mockito) to create a test instance of DateService returning a fixed date:

```
Date fixedDate = new Date(); //use any settings you need for your test
DateService mockedDateService = mock(DateService.class);
when(mockedDateService.getCurrentDate()).thenReturn(fixedDate);
```