# JUnit Test of Timeline

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, junit, timeline

I'm currently moving a Node in JavaFX via a DoubleProperty and Timeline. When I display it in a window, everything works as planned. However, I need to run some JUnit 5 tests.

Below is a simplified version of the Gui and Junit class. I already tried to

-use a while loop, checking the status of the Timeline

-set a listener on the Timeline

-use Thread.sleep for waiting

```
public DoubleProperty x = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

public GuiClass(){ //Constructor
    KeyValue keyValueX = new KeyValue(x, 10);
    Timeline driveTimeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), keyValueX)
            );
    driveTimeline.play();
}
```

Junit:

```
class Junit {

    @Test
    void test() {

        GuiClass test = new GuiClass();
//Never finishes
//      while(test.driveTimeline.getStatus() != Animation.Status.STOPPED)
//      {
//          System.out.print(".");
//      }

//      test.driveTimeline.setOnFinished((pActionEvent) ->
//        {
//            System.out.println(test.x.get());
//         });      

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     System.out.println(test.x.get()); // Returns 0.0
}
```

My question is: How can I let the Junit wait until the Timeline is finished?

Side note: In my original program, the timeline induces several functions when it finishes, which are then being asserted. But the Timeline never seems to finish.

Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001671/override-java-system-currenttimemillis-for-testing-time-sensitive-code