# Do we have setCurrentMillisFixed in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, zoneddatetime

In Joda we have setCurrentMillisFixed method which can be used to set current system time:

`DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem();`

In Java 8 i am trying :

`ZonedDateTime.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone());`

But lot of test cases are failing, i am guessing this has something to do with how the date is being set.

Similarly, for fast forwarding time, in Joda

`DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(theFuture);`

In Java 8 i tried:

`ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant().plusMillis());`

Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Override Java System.currentTimeMillis for testing time sensitive code*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2001671/642706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several variants of `Clock`, you can use [`Clock.fixed(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) to always return a specified instant.

Comment: `Clock.fixed(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault()); ` is this enough ? or do i have to pass this to ZonedDatetime ?

Comment: for adding few seconds:      `ZonedDateTime.now(Clock.fixed(Instant.now().plusMillis(1000), ZoneId.systemDefault()));
`

Comment: still no luck, basically i think when we do `DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(theFuture);` we set a future date, i tried a lot of ways, not able to do it using Java 8

Answer (score 2):

## Pass a `Clock` implementation

The [Answer by Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51381255/642706) is correct. The `Clock` class offers several **alternate implementations that tell a lie**, to facilitate testing. Here is more explanation how to use them.

Every `now` method in *java.time* take an optional `Clock` argument.

The classes representing a moment:

- [`Instant.now( Clock clock )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now(java.time.Clock))
- [`OffsetDateTime.now( Clock clock )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#now(java.time.Clock))
- [`ZonedDateTime.now( Clock clock )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now(java.time.Clock))

The classes *not* representing a moment:

- [`LocalDate.now( Clock clock )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now(java.time.Clock))
- [`LocalTime.now( Clock clock )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#now(java.time.Clock))
- [`LocalDateTime.now( Clock clock )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now(java.time.Clock))

If omitted, you get the system default `Clock` implementation, the true clock.

The `Clock` class offers several handy alternate implementations, available by calling static class methods. See [my Answer on a similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26570951/642706) for a list with descriptions.

If you want to override that true clock with a false clock for testing purposes, pass some other `Clock` implementation.

As an example, we make a `Clock` that falsely reports a fixed single moment, a clock that does not “tick”. We set that single moment to be two hours from now.

```
Clock twoHoursFuture = 
    Clock.fixed( 
        Instant.now().plus( Duration.ofHours( 2 ) ) ,  // Capture the current moment, then add a `Duration` span-of-time of two hours. Result is a moment in the future.
        ZoneId.systemDefault()                         // Or specify another time zone if that is an aim of your testing.
    )
;
```

Given some code such as this method:

```
public void someMethod( Clock clock ) {
    …
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( clock ) ;
    …
}
```

… your test harness passes a false clock:

```
// Test harness passes `twoHoursFuture`.
someObject.someMethod( twoHoursFuture ) ;
```

… while your production code passes the true clock, obtained by calling [`Clock.systemDefaultZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#systemDefaultZone()):

```
// Production-code passes the result of calling `Clock.systemDefaultZone()`.
someObject.someMethod( Clock.systemDefaultZone() ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).