# How to mock the system clock for tests in spring boot applications?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following static function:

```
public static String formatTimestamp() {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    return dateFormat.format(new Date());
  }
```

I want to create a test that makes sure it works properly, and in order to do that, I believe I need to override the system's current time so that I can assert proper values.

I created the following test class:

```
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.slf4j.MDC;


import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class LogUtilsTest {

  @Test
  void test_Format_Timestamp_Success() {
    String expectedNow = "2023-09-26T12:00:00.000Z";
    Instant.now(Clock.fixed(Instant.parse(expectedNow), ZoneOffset.UTC));

    String currentTimeStamp = LogUtils.formatTimestamp();

    assertEquals(expectedNow, currentTimeStamp);
  }
}
```

Whenever I run the test, it returns that the expected is not equal to the actual value, as the actual value equals the time when the test runs.

I followed the following answers:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-override-system-time
- [Override Java System.currentTimeMillis for testing time sensitive code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001671/override-java-system-currenttimemillis-for-testing-time-sensitive-code)

But nothing works. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stop using outdated classes like `SimpleDateFormat` or `java.util.Date`. move ower to the newer `java.time.*` API

Comment: Have you tried to print out the `currentTimeStamp to see what is wrong?

Comment: BTW: As I know the fixed clock only works with the `java.time` API

Comment: Hello @Jens, yes I did try to print the ```currentTimeStamp``` and it always returns the time that the test runs at. I'll try to apply your changes and see if it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

While it's technically possible to change all ways the JVM retrieves time, I'd advise against it. Altering such fundamental behavior can lead to unpredictable results, make your code harder to understand for others, and introduce potential bugs or issues in areas you might not expect. It's generally a good practice to avoid modifying global or static states, especially for something as universal as time retrieval.

That said, if you're curious about the concept, you might want to look into "static method mocking" for some examples. But remember, just because you can, doesn't always mean you should.

Regarding your line `Instant.now(Clock.fixed(Instant.parse(expectedNow), ZoneOffset.UTC))`, it's essentially creating a new instance with the specified clock, but it doesn't alter the JVM's default behavior. A better approach might be to pass the clock to your `LogUtils.formatTimestamp()` method. If you're using Spring, you could create your own clock provider as a component. Alternatively, you could design a static class with a setter specifically for your tests.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Hello @Dennis, 
Thank you so much for your suggestion, I'll try to do so and see if that works. :)